# Hiding services with Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-ui

is there any way that some services can be hidden from swagger UI when going into production but when run on localhost be displayed?

EX:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// GET: .../api/SomeController/{id: int}
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">int</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
public IHttpActionResult SomeService(int id) { return Ok();}
```

When i'm running on my environment and go to swagger UI [localhost:12345/swagger/ui/index](http://localhost:12345/swagger/ui/index) i will see that service documentation etc, 
but when i'm on http://someDomain/swagger/ui/index i will not see it.

I've been looking in the documentation but didn't find anything related to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own attribute and use it to exclude that method or whole controller from swagger:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class HideInDocsAttribute:Attribute
{
}
```

And then:

```
public class HideInDocsFilter:IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if(env.IsEnvironment("Production")) {
            foreach (var apiDescription in apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions)
            {
                if (!apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<HideInDocsAttribute>().Any() && !apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<HideInDocsAttribute>().Any()) continue;
                var route = "/" + apiDescription.Route.RouteTemplate.TrimEnd('/');
                swaggerDoc.paths.Remove(route);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```